# Displaying keyboard at the middle(or at desired location) of the screen in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a made a custom keyboard for my app which has just a single row of keys. 
I want to display the keyboard at the centre of the screen rather than in the bottom. 
Is there any way to do it?

i am using this xml code:

```
enter code here

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="12.50%p"
    android:keyHeight="50%p">
<Row>
    <Key 
        android:codes="55"    
        android:keyLabel="7" 
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
    <Key 
        android:codes="56"    
        android:keyLabel="8" />
    <Key 
        android:codes="57"    
        android:keyLabel="9" />
    <Key 
        android:codes="65"    
        android:keyLabel="A" 
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup" 
        android:popupCharacters="aA" 
        android:horizontalGap="6.25%p" />
    <Key
         android:codes="66"    
         android:keyLabel="B" 
         android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup" 
         android:popupCharacters="bB" />

</Row>

</Keyboard>
```

Comment: can you tell what Layout or View you are using for the Keyboard

Comment: I am using the folling xml code:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create below keyboard.xml file

```
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
```

-->

```
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="8"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/k1hover"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/key1" />
    <Key
        android:codes="9"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/k2hover"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/k2"
        />
    <Key
        android:codes="10"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/k3hover"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
         android:keyIcon="@drawable/k3"
        />


</Row>
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="11"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/k4hover"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/k4"
         />
    <Key
        android:codes="12"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/k5hover"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/k5"
       />
    <Key
        android:codes="13"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/k6hover"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/k6"
        />

    <Key
        android:codes="0"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/nexthover"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/keyboardnext" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="14"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/k7hover"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/k7"
        />
    <Key
        android:codes="15"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/k8hover"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/k8"
        />
    <Key
        android:codes="16"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/k9hover"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/k9"
         />
</Row>
<Row>
     <Key
        android:codes="158"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/dot"
         android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/dothover"
         />

      <Key
        android:codes="7"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/k0"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/k0hover"
         />
    <Key
        android:codes="67"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/backhover"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/keyboard_back"
        />

     <Key
        android:codes="35"
         android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/keydown"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/keydownhover"
         />

</Row>
```

call this keyboard at specific position :

```
    <com.kcs.pd.remote.utils.CustomKeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        android:background="@drawable/keyboardback" >
    </com.kcs.pd.remote.utils.CustomKeyboardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

use this code in java file is as :

```
mKeyboard = new Keyboard(actLiverFunctionTests, R.xml.keyboard);
        mKeyboardView = (CustomKeyboardView) vwParent
                .findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);

        mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboard);
        mKeyboardView
                .setOnKeyboardActionListener(new BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(
                        actLiverFunctionTests));
```